# Using custom UUID Type from SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, guid

I'm currently using the custom [UUID SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html#backend-agnostic-guid-type) type stored on the following folder: `/flask_application/helpers/uuid_creator.py`, which I import on my main model:

```
from flask_application.helpers import GUID

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(GUID(), primary_key=True)
```

Which I later use also, on my foreign key columns on two other tables:

**Passport Table:**

```
from flask_application.helpers import GUID

class Passport(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'passport'

...
user_id = db.Column(GUID(), db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
...
```

**Misc Table:**

```
from flask_application.helpers import GUID


class Misc(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'misc'

...
user_id = db.Column(GUID(), db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

After I saved this, I ran my `python manage.py migrate` command only to find this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 4, in <module>
    from seed import createdata, dropdb, dropdata
  File "C:\www\liu-passport-api\seed.py", line 11, in <module>
    from flask_application import app, db
  File "C:\www\liu-passport-api\flask_application\__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from flask_application.models import (
  File "C:\www\liu-passport-api\flask_application\models\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .misc import *
  File "C:\www\liu-passport-api\flask_application\models\misc.py", line 5, in <module>
    from flask_application.helpers import GUID
  File "C:\www\liu-passport-api\flask_application\helpers\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .auth import (requires_auth, get_user_from_token)
  File "C:\www\liu-passport-api\flask_application\helpers\auth.py", line 11, in <module>
    from flask_application.models import User
ImportError: cannot import name 'User'
```

I would guess the import is not being a problem since the error is not saying `ImportError: No module named UUID`, but rather `ImportError: cannot import name 'User'` for some reason.

Am I implementing this GUID extension from `SQLAlchemy` wrong? User `ImportError` started happening when I added the GUID class for the custom data type, so it shouldn't be an error.

Answer (score 0):

You have circular dependency: `seed` imports flask_application (`__init__.py`), which imports `flask_application.models`, which import `flask_application.models.misc` ...,which import `flask_application.helpers.auth`, which finally imports `flask_application.models` ! And this you have yet to finish to load iter already, you're stuck.

It looks like you have loads of stuff imported in your `__init__.py` files which proves to be a very poor practice (unless you are very careful). Add to that that you do star imports like `from .misc import *`.